# black screen on boot (DVI) - Radeon 9550/9600/X1050 Series - Lubuntu 13.04

Tags: drivers, radeon

I get no signal after boot, yet when I hit the reset button the boot screen shows. What could be the problem?

thanks

monitor: lg flatron W2246T

ps: this is no duplicate as I get no black  screen when I hit the reset button...

xrandr output

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 4096 x 4096
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      60.0
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0
   1152x864       75.0
   1024x768       75.1     60.0
   800x600        75.0     60.3
   640x480        75.0     60.0
   720x400        70.1
S-video disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Comment: Doesn't seem like a duplicate, aaaa (what a horrid name) please update your question to reflect monitor type and let us know if you can test with another monitor.

Comment: hi. monitor is a lg flatron W2246T. Unfortunately its my only one with a dvi....

Comment: How are you connecting? What port is in use. Is it HDMA or DVI or VGA etc?

Comment: it's connected via dvi

Comment: So you have a second monitor? I have an idea but you will have to test a command via ssh or type it in via a second screen.

Comment: yes, I have a second montitor....

Comment: try `xrandr --output LVDS --on`  or `xrandr --output LVDS --off && xrandr --output LVDS --on`  also output the info from xrandr with no arguments if that doesn't work.

Comment: hm. commands do not seem to work. output LVDS not found

Answer (score 0):

Older video cards may fail to produce a good quality high resolution image on DVI. Most likely because of frequency instability (?). Default modeline for 1920x1080 results in a very high frequency that RAMDAC (?) on your video card fails to operate at.

You can try to reduce blanking time (RBT) and as a result lower frequency. You have to add new modelines with xranrd as described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions). Instead of using `cvt` or `gft`, I suggest to use [umc](http://umc.sourceforge.net/). The reason for this is that it can calculate modeline for lower refresh rate with `--rbt`, e.g. my monitor supports as low as 49.9 Hz refresh rate. `cvt` would insist on multiples of 60Hz.

Note on comment reply about `LVDS`... according to your output you should use `DVI-0` when adding and setting new modelines.